# Polars read_excel set option to include filtered rows

Tags: python, python-polars

I've noticed that the Polars read_excel/Xlsx2csv doesn't include rows that are filtered in excel file(s). However, there is an option in Polars read_csv to set xlsx2csv options (xlsx2csv_options: dict[str, Any]).

I've tried to check from Xlsx2csv documentation whether there would be such an option, but couldn't find it. ChatGPT instructed to try "--skip-filtered-rows", but not sure how can I enter that to the Polars read_csv xlsx2csv option as a dictionary?

Workaround I've used is to read the excel file with pandas first and then read it with polars, but would prefer to do this with polars directly.

```
pl.from_pandas(pd.read_excel(file))
```

xlsx2csv version 0.8.0

polars version 0.15.13

EDIT: Found the same issue in github as well: https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/issues/246

Looks like there was added a new setting to xlsx2csv "skip_hidden_rows" in the version 0.8.0. However, when I tried to use the below, I am still getting only the filtered rows from the excel files.

```
pl.read_excel(file, xlsx2csv_options={"skip_hidden_rows": False})
```

Comment: You could install from the commit that added the new functionality e.g. `pip install git+https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv.git@9b6c2df79f2a49306e5aaca2a7b4a94a41198aab` - the update hasn't been released yet.

Comment: You are right, I thought it was part of the version 0.8.0 already. Thanks a lot, that worked and the files were read as complete after installing the package the way you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, had the same thing as well...